# SVG Filter Showing Incorrect Colors

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I found [this tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/03/10/creative-gooey-effects/) and thought it was interesting. However, there's an issue I have in certain browsers. Instead of using the pink color, white shows where the blending should be happening. I'm not sure if this is because of the `feColorMatrix` or even `feComposite`? Perhaps this is related to the Chrome version (the issue shown occurs in Chrome 63), but [support seems fine for SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html).

Is there any fix to this issue that I could apply?

[Codepen link.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYeyXZ)

**Image of issue:**

[image: Goo showing White]

```js
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1});

tl.from("#two", 2, {ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.7, 0.7, false), scale: .2, y: -60})
  .to("#two", 1, {y: 100})
  .to("#two", 1, {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), y: -60, scale: .2})
;
```

```css
.container {
  -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url("#goo");
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f59393;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#two {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="one" class="box"></div>
  <div id="two" class="box"></div>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm running Chrome 67 and it is not happening for me.  So if it was a bug, it seems to have been fixed now.

Comment: Yeah... I'm only seeing the bug in version 63, which is used in certain software I'm targeting. Not sure if there's anyway around it... perhaps a way to force the default color to be the background color I'm using, instead of white. If you're familiar with OBS Studio, you can recreate the error in its browser source.